# How to automatically transfer a file when two androids are in the same vicinity?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-wifi, transfer

Im working on an app that asks the user to input 5 words. I would like the app to notify the user if someone in the same vicinity has any words that match with the user. I was wondering whats the best way to go about this. Im not sure about bluetooth because I believe it requires the user to manualy make a connection with the other user. I was thinking of maybe uploading the users gps location and comparing it with other users. To be honest I have no idea how to go about this. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have all devices communicate their location and "words" to a shared webservice.  The webservice can then report back whether their are matches in the vicinity.  Don't get distracted by fancy nfc/wifi/bt ideas if you don't need to :)

Comment: Ya that sounds like good advice. Any recomendations on webservices?

Comment: I personally like Azure Mobile Services from Microsoft